# Are these problems NP-Complete?

Tags: graphs, computability, np-complete, matching

I got 2 decision problem that I need to answer if they are in P or they are NP complete:

> 1.Just like subset sum:
>   given the integers or natural numbers ${\displaystyle w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n}}$ does any subset of them sum to precisely ${\displaystyle W}$?

but now instead of $W$:

> does any subset of them sum to $W'$  such: $W-10 \leq W'\leq W+10$ ?

I think this problem is NP complete.

My idea was to create a reduction from subset sum to this problem:
I thought to add the all the number between -10 to 10 : {-10,-9,-8....,0,1,2,....10} to ${\displaystyle w_{1},\ldots ,w_{n}}$
and now i can find any $W'$.

> 2.Just like 3-dimensional matching:
>   Let X, Y, and Z be finite, disjoint sets, and let T be a subset of X × Y × Z. That is, T consists of triples (x, y, z) such that x ∈ X, y ∈ Y, and z ∈ Z. Now M ⊆ T is a 3-dimensional matching if the following holds: for any two distinct triples $(x_1, y_1, z_1) ∈ M$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2) ∈ M,$ we have $x_1 ≠ x_2, y_1 ≠ y_2$, and $z_1 ≠ z_2$.

But now:

> each vertex can be in only 3 triples.Is there a $M' ⊆ M$ that is a perfect matching?

I think this problem is in P .to prove this I thought about (hopefully polynomial) algorithm:

`a.take a random vertex and find all the matches that he's in .`

`b.If the vertex is in only 1 match,put this match in M' and delete it form M.
otherwise do nothing.`
(and delete all the vertex in this match from the hypergraph and all the matching they are in)

repeat a and b 3 times.It should take $O(3|X||Y||Z||M|)$.

Is my answers right?

Comment: What's the context where you encountered these tasks?  Please credit the original source.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: You're asking two completely unrelated questions. The usual rule is one question per post.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-Complete. Membership to $\mathsf{NP}$ is trivial. To see that it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard, you can reduce it from Subset Sum. Let $\langle S_1, W_1 \rangle$ be an instance of Subset Sum. Define $S_2$ as the multiset obtained by multiplying each number in $S_1$ by $100$, and $W_2 = 100 W_1$. The instance for your problem is $\langle S_2, W_2 \rangle$.

If there is a set $C_1 \subseteq S_1$ such that $\sum_{x \in C_1} x  = W_1$, then let $W'$ be the sum of the elements in corresponding subset for $S_2$. We have $W' = \sum_{x \in C_1} 100x = 100 \cdot W_1 = W_2 \in \left[W_2-10, W_2+10\right]$.

If there is a set $C_2 \subseteq S_2$ such that the sum $W' = \sum_{x \in C_2} x$ of its elements satisfies $W_2-10 \le W' \le W_2+10$, then pick $y   = W' - W_2$, so that $W'  = W_2 + y$ and $y \in [-10, 10]$.
We must have $y=0$ since $W' = W_2 + y = y \pmod{100}$ and $W'$ must be a multiple of $100$. This shows that $W' = W_2$  and that the corresponding subset of $S_1$ has a sum of $\sum_{x \in C_2} \frac{x}{100} = \frac{W'}{100} = \frac{W_2}{100} = W_1$.

Your second problem is already known to be $\mathsf{NP}$-Complete even when when no vertex occurs in more than three triples. See problem SP1 in  "Garey & Johnson, Computer and intractability: a guide to the theory of NP-completeness".

Comment: Thank you very much! I just didn't understand this part: $W'∈[W'-10,W'+10]$ and $W′+y∈[W′−10,W′+10] $ .  I need to prove that $W−10≤W′≤W+10 $ ,so how is this relevant?

Comment: I'm using $W$ to refer to the target value of the original subset sum instance (just like you do) but I'm using $W'$ to refer to the target value of your modified subset sum instance (that you still call $W$ in your question). I agree that this is a bit confusing because you use $W'$ to denote the sum of $C$... I'll change the notation.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: It's is clearer. But I still don't understand why $W_2∈[W_2−10,W_2+10]$  solve the first part. Maybe i didn't state it correctly,but I need to show that $W_2∈[W_1−10,W_1+10]$. 
 So in the second part it should be also $W_1−10≤W′≤W_1+10$.Am I wrong?

Comment: Wait. You are given a "modified subset sum" instance $\langle S, W \rangle$ which consists of a set $S$ and a target value $W$. You want to find a subset of $S$ with sum $W' \in [ W - 10, W+ 10 ]$ right?

Therefore, when the input instance is $\langle S_2, W_2 \rangle$ the goal is to find a subset of $S_2$ with sum $W' \in [ W_2 - 10, W_2 + 10 ]$. I showed that there exists a subset with sum $W' = W_2$, which satisfies the condition $W' \in [ W_2 - 10, W_2 + 10 ]$.

Comment: Oh,I see what you mean,my bad.You were right. :) Another thing,the only reason to multiply by 100 is for $y=0$ in the second part? Because I don't see how it is helping in the first part.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It is intuitive that it plays no role in the first part since any solution to subset sum is a solution to your modified version (which has weaker constraints). The interesting part is showing that these weaker constraints are actually equivalent to to original equality constraint, and this requires multiplying by 100 (by the way, 100 is just a round number that will do).

Comment: OK,thank you very much!! :)